# If $f$ is odd and $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ is known, then do we know $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}f(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

Suppose $f(x)$ is odd, smooth, vanishes at infinity, and that we know $I=\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ and $c_n=\lim_{x\to 0}f^{(n)}(x)$ for all nonnegative integers $n.$

Can we express $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}f(x)dx$ in terms of any of these known values?

It seems like this might be possible based using power series and/or integration by parts, but I can't find a way.

Comment: no, it is not possible if $f$ is just smooth, because derivatives at zero say nothing about the function away of a neighborhood of zero. Also saying that its an odd function says, again, nothing in this context, because the region of integration is $(0,\infty )$

Comment: @Masacroso that's not entirely true. The odd condition guarantees $f(0)=0$ and given the smooth condition that would at least guarantee the integral does not have a singularity. OP's biggest problem is that smooth doesn't imply analytic which doesn't imply uniform convergence of a series for the whole interval.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I agree, I didn't saw that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I'd be willing to add the assumption of analyticity and even infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: @WillG infinite radius is not enough, you need uniform convergence.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Uniform convergence of a power series? I don't think that is ever possible for a function that vanishes at infinity?